# Redefine template used to create a JUnit 5 class via "Create test" feature of IntelliJ 2019

Tags: templates, intellij-idea, junit, junit5, junit-jupiter

The menu item `Code` > `Generate…` > `Test…` displays this dialog box.

[image]

…and produces a method like this in the resulting test class:

```
@Test
void fromDuration () {
}
```

I want the [`@DisplayName`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/DisplayName.html) annotation (new in JUnit 5) to be automatically inserted as well, for each test method being generated. Like this:

```
@Test
@DisplayName( "NameGoesHere" )
void fromDuration () {
}
```

➥ Is there a way to change the way IntelliJ generates the test to include the `@DisplayName` annotation?

I looked for some template to edit, but could not find one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JUnit 5 method template can be configured in `Settings` (`Preferences` on Mac) | `Editor` | `File and Code Templates` | `Code` tab, **JUnit 5 Test Method**:

[image: method template]

Change this:

```
@org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
void ${NAME}() {
  ${BODY}
}
```

…to this:

```
@org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
@org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName ( "NameGoesHere" )
void ${NAME}() {
  ${BODY}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new template group and then live template

```
@org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
@org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName("$TEST_NAME$")
void $METHOD_NAMES$(){
$END$
$BODY$
}
```

[image]

[image]

Type test and see the template render on the java class